# Process function for dynamically added DOM element

Tags: jquery

I would like to process certain initialization steps whenever an item with a certain class is added anywhere in the DOM. This includes applying some style attributes to its parent (this is why I cannot use CSS), and also binding to the click event.

The following code works when element is static (was already on the page after `document.ready`):

```
$(function(){
  //... global initialization code
  $('.myclass').each(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    parent.css({cursor:'pointer'}); //apply CSS style to the parent
    parent.click(function(event){
      //... event handler
    });        
  });    
});
```

Is it possible to convert it to handle dynamically added elements and how?

Comment: Use "event delegation" instead: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Comment: You used to be able to use the DOMSubtreeModified event to do these things but I believe it has been deprecated with no other replacement option. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events

Comment: @m90: Which event would take care of the element being added (without any particular action from the user)?

Comment: @sbeliv01: I tried that, did not work in Chrome. Could have been mistaken with the syntax, but I'm fairly positive it's just not supported.

Comment: Sorry, I seem to have misunderstod your question. There is no such thing as a working DOMMutationObserver implemtation at the moment but you could always trigger a custom event on your element's creation.

Comment: @m90: Could you please elaborate on firing custom events when the element is created?

Comment: Well that would depend on how you create the element? Is it injected via JS? Do you have access to the code that is injecting the content into the DOM?

Comment: @Neolisk `$('<div class="myClass"></div>').appendTo("body").trigger("created")` would fire a custom event when the element is created.

Comment: @m90: Yes, I do have access to that code.

Comment: @KevinB: Looks interesting, let me experiment with it for some time.

Comment: @Kevin B's comment pretty much sums it up. Add a `.trigger('event-name-thingy')` after the DOM manipulation has happened and listen for that event later on.

Comment: @m90: Can I listen to a yet-non-existing event (which would be the case)?

Comment: Yes, that's possible.

Comment: @m90: Thanks for your help, you can post your ideas into an answer of your own, I will gladly upvote it.

Comment: Thanks but I'll just agree with everything that Kevin B said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no cross-browser "added" or "created" event, you'll have to find another way to accomplish it.

Make your CSS changes in a stylesheet:

```
.myClass {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

and then use event delegation for the click event:

```
$(document).on("click",".myClass",function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    parent.doSomething();
});
```

Another alternative (as pointed out in comments) is to trigger a custom event after you add the element.

```
$(document).on("added", ".myClass", function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    parent.doSomething();
});
//... later on in your code ...
$('<div class="myClass"></div>').appendTo("#someotherel").trigger("added");
```

This is essentially the same thing as simply doing this, which is what i was mentioning in my comments:

```
var parent = $("#someotherel");
parent.append('<div class="myClass"></div>').css("cursor","pointer").click(...
```

Comment: I cannot make changes in CSS, because it needs to apply on the **parent** of .myClass. As far as I know, you cannot select parents in CSS.

Comment: @Neolisk There's also no way of you running code when a new element is added without a horribly inefficient setInterval, or running it immediately after the code that actually adds the element(which is the preferred way of doing it).

Comment: Custom event solution looks like the way to go for now, since I prefer to minimize the amount of changes to be made in JS. Thanks for your answer - very informative.

Comment: Regarding your last update, I would prefer to keep CSS updates away from the code that creates nodes, since it's part of a UI library. Also to follow DRY principle.

Comment: @Neolisk Oh, i agree, i'm just pointing out that you knew all this. It's no different than having a function that you call to trigger the ui updates. It's all in how you want that code to be triggered. Also, just for completeness, the livequery plugin mentioned by Mohammad Adil is another solution, it basically monkeypatches all of the jquery manipulation methods and does this custom event thing itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.on()` for dynamically added elements -

```
$(document).on('click','.myclass',function(event){
   //... event handler
});
```

Comment: The problem is I need something like on('added', function() {...}), because it needs to execute whenever the element was added, but I did not click nor hover on it. Is there anything like that?